# Visual Studio Code Python extension 'Run File in Terminal' not working

Tags: python

Using VSC Python extension 'Run File in Terminal' has suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Asking and answering your own question is fine, but the answer should be posted as, well, an answer.

Comment: OK AMC - Got it - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spent two days, trying every fix I could find on the net. Nothing worked. In desperation, turned off Malwarebytes (using Quit Malwarebytes from the sys tray icon). VSC Python 'Run File in Terminal' now works !!. Turns out to be the Ransomeware Protection layer causing the problem. VSC runs fine with this layer disabled. Hope this helps someone else. Cheers

Update 09.03.20
After constant badgering from Malwarebytes I installed their latest release, version 4.1.0.56, for my system (Win 7). Malwarebytes is still duff running VSC 'Run File in Terminal', until I turn off 'Ransomeware Protection'. So it looks like I will have to put up with Malwarebytes badgering me about this protection being turned off, or junk Malwarebytes, which I have paid for. Cheers Russ